# Tag merge request: [swtoolkit] into [swt]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I think [swtoolkit](/questions/tagged/swtoolkit) is a synonym of [swt](/questions/tagged/swt). Can it be merged into [swt](/questions/tagged/swt)?